# Any Javascript event occurring when user clicks Stop load button?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to run some Javascript when the user clicks the <kbd>Stop Load</kbd>-button (red <kbd>X</kbd> in most browsers) or hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> on the keyboard, which usually does the same.

I've seen questions here covering the <kbd>Esc</kbd> button by hooking onto `document.body.onkeyup`, but couldn't find anything covering mouse click on the <kbd>Stop</kbd> button.

Answer (score 5):

Internet Explorer has a `document.onstop` event that is fired, but other browsers don't seem to support that.  Note that it's fired when the user clicks Stop or hits Esc, OR if the user navigates to another page during page load, which has the same effect.

I don't believe there is a reliable way to trigger an event on clicking Stop in other browsers.  Perhaps it would be possible to do something like: keeping the connection to the server open (as in the [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) approach), streaming some sort of keep-alive down the connection, and detecting if the stream ends (as I assume it would if the Stop button were clicked).

Comment: Thanks. For my specific case I only have to support IE, so onstop should do the trick.

Comment: Well after further testing onstop seems to be not quite what I need after all. It also fires when navigating away from your page, and only once. So if the sequence is like 1. Navigate away, 2. cancel navigation, onstop only fires on the first event - oppsite of my need.

Comment: When you navigate away, that cancels loading of the page you were on.  If you then click Stop, that will cancel loading of the new page.  I would expect there to be two onstop events fired, but for different documents.

Comment: Yea, you're probably right. Even if that new page is not done loading yet. I think I'll rethink the whole concept of what I'm trying to do, avoiding the need for this event.

Answer (score 4):

If it's images that are still getting loaded on the page, you can use the [`onabort`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_img_onabort.asp) event to monitor for the *stop load*.

Monitoring for the *mouse click* should be impossible, as it doesn't happen **inside** the current browsing window.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any cross browser way of doing this.

However, IE has a special event, [`onstop`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_Events#Microsoft-specific_events) which occurs on the `body` when the stop button is pressed. You cannot override the stop button functionality (that is, you cannot cancel it), but you can detect that it has happened in IE.