# Javascript event on page load abortion

Tags: javascript, browser, abort

I have a page with Paypal payment link, my page use a location.href to redirect user to payment page. But, if he abort the page with browser stop button, I would like to show a message with a link.
How can I get the page load stop event?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any Javascript event occurring when user clicks Stop load button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728158/any-javascript-event-occurring-when-user-clicks-stop-load-button)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **document.onstop**

Occurs when the user aborts the loading of the document.
If an onstop event occurs, the onload event is not fired on the document.

```js
     document.onstop = OnStopDocument;
        function OnStopDocument () {
            alert ("The loading of the document has been aborted.");
        }
        function OnLoadDocument () {
            alert ("The document has been loaded.");
        }
```

```html
<body onload="OnLoadDocument ()">
   Loading the document
</body>
```

Comment: Should this work on the caller page? `document.onstop` is not working on caller page

Comment: This is an IE-only solution...